# What is this type of detent mechanism called?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, gears, mechanisms, springs

I'm trying to find out what this common rotary detent mechanism is actually called. I see them in all sorts of cheap plastic toys, and I'd like to see if I can find them for sale, but I don't know what to search for! I modeled this one in blender for a personal project. If it's not clear in the image, the inner barrel has 4 springs that quantize the rotation of the outer ring. Is this (or something similar) something I could find in bulk, or are they always designed ad-hoc?

[image: detent mechanism]

Comment: Looks like a custom job, some kind variation on a flat radial-finger-spring. Nice shape for an EDM part. You might well find it on Alibaba, but no telling what the vendor would call it.

Comment: http://www.ehcknobs.com/pdfs/Detent%20Knob.pdf

Comment: @Phil Sweet - Yeah, that's a ball and spring style detent. Serves the same purpose, but I'm trying to reduce my part count, and make it completely from injection-molded plastic.

Comment: If you buy it, the parts count is 1 :)

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure that is some kind of pawl and spring disconnect.  Similar to what gives a bike casette the ratcheting connection, but yours is bi-directional like a ball detent.

Closest cheap thing I could find is a rotary selector switch.  It'd have extra electrical connections that you may not want or need.  They tend not to have many positions though; I've used an 8 position one that had nice ball detents.

Comment: It seems that pawls are specifically used with ratchets to prevent rotation in one direction. I can't seem to find a single example of a bi-directional analog, except for a ball detent, but I'm trying to minimize the number of parts I need. I can tell that you understand the functionality I described, and I appreciate the quick reply!

Comment: most common pawls are used in ratchets but term applies to any lever that stops motion- in this case motion between two rotating components.  a good bit of design needs to go into these so depending on budget and quantity you may need to just approach a shaft coupler manufacturer.  they do tend to have modular reconfigurable designs ready to roll though.

Comment: I think a shaft coupler manufacturer would be overkill in my case. I'm just making a small plastic counter with a numbered disk that rotates under a window. This pawl and gear will be the most complicated part, so if I can find a wholesaler, I could design the other parts around it and have them injection molded cheaply. Plenty of places offer kits of assorted gears and such, but I guess I might have to design this part myself.

Comment: if you're going to injection mold, some already make integrated ones of these in cheap plastic toys.  cheap plastic gears are also injection molded.  you can also start with a 3d printed prototype; even one at 2X the scale to make it easier to produce.

Comment: Yeah, my plan is to prototype with a 3d printer, then get quotes on injection molding. It just seems like such a ubiquitous component, I'm surprised there isn't anyone that has them in stock by the thousands, like the gear kits you can find at hobby shops.

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand it, this mechanism performs very much like the notched scroll wheel of some mice.

[image]

Although, probably that is not seem to be the same size or transfer the same load as the one you have in your picture.

Comment: Very similar, yes. I don't need a specific load transfer; that's something I can fiddle with later if need be. It's just meant for a mechanical selector dial with discrete positions, like an old-school television dial, sans the electronics.

Comment: @Adam an unpowered stepping motor can provide the detent feel